# Unity C# class throws null in other namespace

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

I have a complicated issue. Here is some of my code, which is a class for game tiles.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace game_tiles {
    public class GameTile {

        public GameObject tilePrefab;
        public bool isPassable;
        public float moveCost;
    }

    public class GameTiles : MonoBehaviour {

        public GameTile redTile;
        public GameObject redTilePrefab;
        public bool redTileIsPassable;
        public float redTileMoveCost;

        public void Main() {

            GameTile redTile = new GameTile();
            redTile.tilePrefab = redTilePrefab;
            redTile.isPassable = redTileIsPassable;
            redTile.moveCost = redTileMoveCost;
            print(redTile);
        }
    }
}
```

When the above code runs, it prints to the unity console: `game_tiles.GameTile`

Completely normal, right?

However, I want to use the code in a different file, using this code here:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using game_tiles;

namespace board_manager {
    public class BoardManager : MonoBehaviour {

        GameTiles gameTiles;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start() {

            gameTiles = GameObject.Find("Game Tile Class").GetComponent<GameTiles>();

            GameTile redTile = gameTiles.redTile;
            print(redTile);  
        }
    }
}
```

This code, for some reason, prints `Null` to the Unity console, and, thus, I cannot use any of the variables in the `redTile` object. How can I get both programs to print `game_tiles.GameTile`? Thank you for any help.

P.S. Sorry about all of the similar gameTile variables. I could not think of different names. d=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined a new variable in the constructor, when you wanted to use the class-level variable it looks like:

```
public class GameTiles : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameTile redTile;
    public GameObject redTilePrefab;
    public bool redTileIsPassable;
    public float redTileMoveCost;

    public void Main() {

        this.redTile = new GameTile();
        this.redTile.tilePrefab = redTilePrefab;
        this.redTile.isPassable = redTileIsPassable;
        this.redTile.moveCost = redTileMoveCost;
        print(this.redTile);
    }
}
```

Notice the constructor now uses `this`. It's not required but used to illustrate that we're using the global variable, not creating our own (`var redTile` created a local copy that doesn't propagate automatically up to the class).

Comment: I'm sorry that I do not quite understand how this works, but it did. Thank you so much. Maybe I will research this more to figure out how it works!

Comment: This might sound bizarre, but recently I moved all my code to  an Ubuntu computer from Windows 10, and now, even with your answer, the new code still returns null! It is not working any more, even though I reproduced your answer exactly. Is this a known problem, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong? As I said, at the time, your answer was just fine.

Comment: Never mind It was just a simple problem with execution order. I fixed that by changing the execution order of the scripts. lol.